# Why my extend() method in Javascript don't work for 3 and more objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, extend, javascript-objects

I have 3 object.

netBuilder
Numbering
NumberingMethodDefault

And i have some extend method.

```
extend: function (Child, Parent) {
  var F = function () {};
  F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
  Child.prototype = new F();
  Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
  Child.superclass = Parent.prototype;
  this.mixin(Child, Parent);
},
/**

 * @param {type} dst
 * @param {type} src
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
mixin: function (dst, src) {
  var tobj = {};
  for (var x in src) {
    if ((typeof tobj[x] == "undefined") || (tobj[x] != src[x])) {
      dst[x] = src[x];
    }
  }
  if (document.all && !document.isOpera) {
    var p = src.toString;
    if (typeof p == "function" && p != dst.toString && p != tobj.toString &&
      p != "\nfunction toString() {\n    [native code]\n}\n") {
      dst.toString = src.toString;
    }
  }
}
```

Than i try that Numbering extends from netBuilder and NumberingMethodDefault extends from Numbering.

```
oopUtility.extend(Numbering, netBuilder);
oopUtility.extend(NumberingMethodDefault, Numbering);
```

And call superclassses

```
Numbering.superclass.constructor.call(this, arguments);
NumberingMethodDefault.superclass.constructor.call(this, arguments);
```

Numbering has method setNumber().
I have access in Numbering to netBuilder methods, but in NumberingMethodDefault i can't execute method setNumber() from Numbering.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NumberingMethodDefault> has no method 'setNumber'
```

Than i console.log() what is superclass for NumberingMethodDefault

```
console.log(NumberingMethodDefault.superclass);
//and it was netBuilder, not Numbering! о_О
```

How can i make it work. I need extend for 3 or more objects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your call to `mixin` manually copies properties from one object to the other, and is overwriting the `.superclass` assignment. If you're emulating class inheritance you won't need mixins in this way, so remove that code altogether and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Maybe i need some if changes  


`if ((typeof tobj[x] == "undefined") || (tobj[x] != src[x]) || tobj[x] != superclass)`  


!? :)

Comment: Yes, it's work!!!

`if (((typeof tobj[x] == "undefined") || (tobj[x] != src[x])) && (src[x] != src.superclass)) {
                dst[x] = src[x];
            }`